# feature image can not share on facebook in single.php

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, share

I want to share post feature image in my facebook account.
For that I have use the facebook share button code.
It will working fine with my one template page, but as I have use this code in single.php, it could not work, I can not identify the reason.
I have use the code in my single.php file like:

```
//header
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=196109523902137&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

//to get feature image url
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($_GET['id']) );
$share_url  =  get_permalink(get_the_ID());
<a id="ref_fb"  href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=
100&p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&p[summary]=<?php echo $description;?
>&p[url]=<?php echo urlencode($share_url);?>&`p[images][0]=<?php $url;?>"
 onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', ``'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no
,scrollbars=no,height=400,width=600');return false;">`
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/_images/fb.png" alt=""/></a>
```

I have use the facebook debuger tool and I get the one warning in image like,
"og:image could not be downloaded or is too small"
So accroding to that warning, I have add the big image of at least 200x200px
but even can not get proper image.

other thinks that i have notice in facebook debuger,
I could see the "When shared, this is what will be included" in this portion I could see the feature image very well but not from my page.

I have also notice that feature image has been displayed in given below portion of my debuger screen:
"Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties" in og:image as.

Also notice "These are the raw tags that we found" the found meta tag as

Or you can see this also info directly from,
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
filling the url like: http://www.novelwall.org/dev/bussiness-opportunities-client-success-post1/?id=1001&&tabName=content-1&&page=solu

Comment: no no it is not any 'PDF' image, it is just a look like that and name like that, otherwise it is normal jpg image.

Comment: No, it is a PDF image. I can clearly see it in the header of your website's source code. `<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.novelwall.org/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/big_Novelwall_pdf_gray_design-300x300.jpg"/>`

Answer (score 0):

In the `<head>` of your website, you are declaring the `meta og:image` as the 'PDF' image.

Instead, you need to declare the post's featured image.

A good starting point is here: [Featured Image og:image](http://ryanscowles.com/2013/01/set-wordpress-featured-image-thumbnail/)

Comment: I have just call one function from my function.php which is declare og:img tag dynamically as what post is load. and it is not any PDF image, it is just look like that and name like that, otherwise it is normal jpg image.

Comment: Have a look at the source code of your website. Line 138. It references an image which is a thumbnail of the 'PDF' sign.

Comment: ok if you think it is PDF image, now I have replace it with another one. now can you look over this, please. this is new meta tag value, <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.novelwall.org/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/News_28.07.2014l-300x165.jpg"/>

Comment: Now it has been updated to: http://www.novelwall.org/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/News_28.07.2014l-300x165.jpg

Comment: You need WordPress to dynamically set the og:image tag based on the featured image of the post. The link I put in the answer shows you how to do this. You would complete this in the header.php file

Comment: I have already doing the thing and put the code which is where it require realted to tag in my function.php and header file. But even it can not work

Answer (score 0):

@ Telford Computer-DoctorL, 
I have already put the code which is where it require realted to tag in my function.php and header file. But even it can not work.
my code snippet it like in function.php:

```
function insert_image_src_rel_in_head()
{
    global $post;
    if ( !is_singular()) //if it is not a post or a page
    return;

    if(!has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ))
    {
            //the post does not have featured image, use a default image
            $default_image="http://example.com/image.jpg"; //replace this with a default image on your server or an image in your media library
            echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
    }
    else
    {
            $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
            echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '"/>';
    }
    echo "";
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_image_src_rel_in_head', 5 );
```

and because of that we see the og:image meta tag in header.

Comment: Remove all `og:image` references from the header and put the following in. `<?php $fb_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'thumbnail'); ?>
<?php if ($fb_image) : ?>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $fb_image[0]; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: I have tried what you say but even it can not work and give multiple image instead of one feature image in facebook share popup.